# Using variable in a different function of the same controller laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i know this question looks like a easy one and asked many times, but i tried all the possible solution and nothing seems to work. so please don't mark this as duplicate until a solution has been found. So here is the problem, 
I have defined a variable $msg_body in tabloader function.
I want to use it in tabloader1 function which is in the same controller.

here is the code and all the solutions that i tried, below is my tabloader function

```
public function tabloader(Request $request){
    $msg_body= Message::where('id', $request->id)->value('body');
    $msg_topic= Message::where('id', $request->id)->value('topic');

    $this->tabloader1($msg_body);
    //$name = $request->$msg_body;
    //$a = new RtrController();
    //$a->tabloader1();
    //Session::put('key', $msg_body);
    //$response = Response::make('Hello World');
    //return  $response->withCookie(Cookie::make('name', 'value', $msg_body));



     //DB::table('sendmessages')->insert(array('body1'=>$msg_body, 'phone_nos'=>'1111'));
    //foreach($item_nos as $item_no)
    //Sendmessage::insert(array('body1'=>$msg_body, 'phone_nos'=>'1234' ));  //'phone_nos'=>$item_no
    //endforeach

    //return view('adminCenter',compact('prod'));  

}
```

and below is my tabloader1 function

```
public function tabloader1($msg_body){      

    $prod=Message::get()->all();

    $item_nos=DB::table('items')->pluck('phone_no');
    //dd($item_nos);

    $item_ids=DB::table('items')->pluck('id');
    //$name = Session::get('key');
    //$value = Cookie::get('name');

    //Sendmessage::create(array('body1' => $value,'phone_nos' => '11113'));

    DB::table('sendmessages')->insert(array('body1'=>$msg_body, 'phone_nos'=>'1111'));
    //foreach($item_nos as $item_no){
        //foreach($item_ids as $item_id){
            //DB::table('sendmessages')->whereId($item_id)->update(array('phone_nos'=>$item_no ));
            //DB::table('sendmessages')->insert(array('body1'=>$msg_body, 'phone_nos'=>'1111'));  





    return view('adminCenter',compact('prod'));  //here i want it to return to .. know the syntax? no

}
```

i am using that variable to insert it into a table sendmessages

and the error is 
"in tabloader1 function, the argument 1 is missing."
I have tried various solutions as you can see the commented lines in code.
Really hoping for a solution, Thanks

Comment: Put here the msg_body var_dump before tabloader1 call.

Comment: Make sure that the message exists and that `$msg_body` is not empty before you call `tabloader1`

Comment: `dd` your `$msg_body`

Comment: The msg_body is not empty, because if i run the insert command in tabloader function, it successfully inserts into the table.

Comment: The code shown would not cause that error; what else calls `tabloader1` in your application?

Comment: Worked after putting the dd command. Thanks Rezrazi, Carlos:)

Comment: As a note, that `//$a->tabloader1();` line worries me a tad (since it would indeed cause that error); is it actually commented out, or is it only commented out in the posted code snippet?

Comment: @chris yes it is been commented out in the code as well. But now there is slight change of situation here. As i had the problem of of retrieving the variable, it was solved by adding the dd command in tabloader fn, everything is working perfectly, the data is getting inserted in tabloader1 fn, but in the end it gives me error that argument 1 is missing. eventhough it is executing past that.

Comment: As a note, `dd` is a helper to "dump and die". This would not solve your problem, @PuneetNaik; it was provided for debugging to make sure you have a message body, and then it would halt code execution.

Answer (score 0):

try  this :

```
public function tabloader(Request $request){
    $msg_body= Message::where('id', $request->id)->select(['body'])->first();
    $msg_topic= Message::where('id', $request->id)->select(['topic'])->first();

   return $this->tabloader1($msg_body);
}


public function tabloader1($msg_body=''){ // '' if empty      
    .
    .
    return view('adminCenter',compact('prod'));  //here i want it to return to .. know the syntax? no
}
```

Comment: I have solved the issue of getting the variable from tabloader fn, i have put the insert command which uses $msg_body in tabloader1 fn, which is executing perfectly. but still i am getting the error that argument 1 is missing.

Comment: @PuneetNaik This code change uses a default value for the message body parameter, so you wouldn't get that error. Do you have another function named tabloader1 in your application?

Comment: argument 1 is missing ..where? what's class name ..? what's row number?

Comment: when i call the tabloader1 function which starts on line 37, it shows shows error that argument 1 is missing on line 37.

Comment: @chris no, i havent used it anywhere else. and i dont know how the insert function which i have defined in tabloader1 fn is executing.